# Assalamualaikum, is this hadith authentic?

Tags: hadith, salat, dua

Narrated by Ibn 'Umar that he said: Whoever says following every (obligatory) prayer and when he goes to bed,
Allahu akbar kabeera adad-ash-shaf'i wa'l-witr, wa kalimaati-Allahi at-taammaali, at-layyibaati-al-mubarakaat (3 times) and
Laa ilaaha ill-Allah "adad-ash-shaf'i wa'l-witr, wa kalimaati-Allahi at-taammaati, at-tayyibaati-al-mubaarakaat (3 times)
(Allah is Most Great the number of the even and the odd, and the blessed, pure, perfect words of Allah)
(There is no god but Allah the number of the even and the odd, and the blessed, pure, perfect words of Allah) they will be light for him in his grave, and light on the jisr (bridge), and light on the siraat (bridge over Hell), until they admit him to Paradise, or until he enters Paradise.
Ibn Abee Shaybah in his Musannaf 10/229 (29256).